# Typescript compiler including external references in compile

Tags: typescript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Referencing TypeScript file includes whole file in output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13461758/referencing-typescript-file-includes-whole-file-in-output)

I have a .ts file that calls a function in another .ts file. I have a reference path setup at the top of the file so that the intellisense works as does the compiler.

However, the compiler is including the compiled version of the external file in the resulting .js file.

It doesn't do this with the definitions for jquery etc, but does do it for all of the .ts files that I write. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Steve Fenton said it's definitely a duplicate.  However, if you want a work around for the time being turn off compile on save in Web Essentials.  I've found that only compiling on build does not reproduce the issue.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for the dupe, did a search and that one didn't come up!