# TypeScript Doesn't Compile Referenced Files

Tags: typescript

I'm using TypeScript to compile some files which reference each other. The files reference each other.

The problem is when I compile them, it includes the compiled contents of the file it references as well.

Example:

```
// in Foo.ts
class Foo {}

// in Bar.ts
/// <reference path='./Foo.ts'/>
class Bar extends Foo {}
```

The output if I tried to just compile Bar.ts would also include the code for Foo.

Based on another thread (mentioned below), it looks like it does this if you use the --out parameter. However, I need to use the out parameter, but don't want it linked (because I'll hook things back up myself).

Does anyone have any idea how to separate these two bits of functionality?

Note:
This is not a duplicate of [Referencing TypeScript file includes whole file in output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13461758/referencing-typescript-file-includes-whole-file-in-output) because that is purely for using Web Essentials. I'm using the command-line compiler directly, though the issue is similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pass a directory name (instead of a file name) to the -out switch, you'll get separate compilation. You'll need version 0.8.2 or later to do this.

Comment: The problem with that is I want to be able to do single files without the extra code (for use with something like Assetic in Symfony, which nandles things one file at a time). I've figured out if I don't use -out at all it works, but it's just weird that using that or not changes how it functions. That seems like an odd bundling of not-necessarily-related-features. +1 though because I didn't know that. =p

Comment: I marked this as the answer since it technically gave me the solution I needed... just not the solution I wanted. =p

Answer (score 1):

I am suffering with the same thing.  [Here is a discussion on codeplex](http://typescript.codeplex.com/discussions/432797) about it, which also references a [bug regarding references](http://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/466).  Please vote it up in case that helps.

We are building a modular SDK, so this repeated code is a real problem.  We ended up using the references only for the Visual Studio tooling, and a custom build system to generate the JavaScript.  The system builds the .d.ts decls for all dependency modules and then uses those decls to build dependent modules, passing the `--noresolve` flag to prevent `<reference ...>` being picked up.